# Hyper-V share a folder between host and instance

Tags: windows, networking, virtualization, hyper-v, virtual-machines

I have a hyper-v server and several VM's (Virtual Machines). All the VM's are connected to an external network.

I have tried to share a folder on the host and connect via the VM, I can do this but I'm prompted for a user name and password (as you would expect). I do not want to enable the "Everyone" group permissions as the physical host server is on a network of other servers.

I have created a new virtual internal network in Hyper-V and given it's adapter a static ip of 33.0.0.100. I have added the virtual adapter to one of the VM's and set to IP to 33.0.0.2 (as advised [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/ee256061%28WS.10%29.aspx)). Again this seems to work but I'm still prompted for a user name and password.

Am I on the right lines here? I just want to share a directory from the host to the vm's without exposing the share to other servers on the network.

Comment: Do you mean you want to share a folder without security only to certain IP addresses? What's wrong with using a login and password anyway?

Comment: "Do you mean you want to share a folder without security only to certain IP addresses?" - Yes. I want to have backup programs such as [Cobian](http://www.educ.umu.se/~cobian/cobianbackup.htm) running on the vm's that dump the backups into the shared folder. I'm thinking that setting up an ftp on the host maybe the best way forward if what I'm asking isn't feasible.

Comment: So I'm thinking you don't have a domain setup if you're using logins and passwords... You can run the backup program as a user who has the share mapped to a drive with the credentials stored. You'll have to login as that user and setup the aforementioned.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisS I think that's the way I will take it. I was just asking the question to make sure I wasn't missing anything obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to get networking from the guest VMs to the management OS involves using passwords.  It doesn't matter whether you create a separate network.  The issues are the same.  Windows authentication is based on users, groups and roles, but not IP addresses.

As Chris mentioned, many people solve this by setting up domains, using Active Directory to manage credentials.

Answer (score 5):

> Again this seems to work but I'm still prompted for a user name and password.

And how is this related to Hyper-V?

Set up your file share and Folder persmissions on the disc to allow UNAUTHENTICATED USERS in and you will not be promted.

"everyone" is "everyone I know" which means "still ask for a password to know who you are".

The question should read "Need to setup a Network share so it does not ask for username and Password". The question is totally neutral to anything even touching Hyper-V.

Comment: I didn't want unauthenticated users to be able to access the share as the server was in a data centre and was visible to other servers. I wanted each hyper-v instance to be able to share a single resource without being prompted for user name and password. I'm no network admin so I didn't have the necessary knowledge to set this up. This is why I came to SF for some guidance. Sorry this annoyed you so much.

Comment: It does not. Hire an admin. This is a site for pro admins - whether you as a home user put a Server into a data Center or not, you are supposed t obe competent in administrating Computers. We assume this, as it is in the FAQ.

Comment: I think your out of line TomTom. You are assuming that because I didn't know the answer to the question I posted that I am a home user and therefore not qualified to ask such a question in this forum. I am a professional software developer setting up a virtual environment to develop in. I have rechecked the faq and I don't think that my question violates the rules in any way. The only unprofessional part of this entire posting is you referring to "stupid network admins". That's just rude.

Comment: So, power user and not admin. Case closed. Most Software develoeprs trying to administrate a System SADLY - I consider this a shame of the profession - are worse than home users.